# Android Studio No variants found for :app

Tags: java, android, youtube

I have been working on a project that was orignally build in 2017-18, the application uses a third party package for youtube player but now it giving error about "An error occurred while initializing the Youtube Player".

Package: com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer:4.1.6

I have tried to upgrade the package nothings helps

Comment: After upgrading the lib, have you changed you code? You can look into this sample app: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/tree/master/core-sample-app